# Getting Facebook Object ID using URL

Tags: facebook, objectid

There are a few different threads of this question but none seem to have a correct answer. Please can someone confirm what is happening with this, dated 26th November 2013.

I have a number of og:urls. I would like to get the object_id of that specific url.

When I use:

```
"SELECT url,id, type, site FROM object_url WHERE url IN ('$url')"
```

I get an ID which is not the same as the ID returned from the Facebook object debugger tool.

It seems like Facebook has limited access to the object_id.
When I use:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids='$url'
```

It returns the url as id.

Is it possible to return the id of a URL using any methods?

Comment: Why do you need the object ID? as far as I know the URL and ID should be interchangeable

Comment: When you query graph.facebook.com/ID then you get more information back than when you get graph.facebook.com/URL.

Comment: Using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug with domain http://www.cnn.com I can get the correct graph ID of 379786107965. However, if I just did http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.cnn.com I get a completely different set of information back.